# Filtering a numpy meshgrid

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, numpy, filter

I would like to filter the values of a numpy meshgrid:

```
X,Y = np.mgrid[-10:10,-10:10]
```

in this case, I would like to remove all coordinates for which `x**2 + y**2 <= 2`.  However, when I try to filter the array directly, for example

```
filter(lambda x,y: x**2 + y**2 >= 2, np.meshgrid[-10:10,-10:10])
```

I get errors because I'm not properly dealing with the array's structure.

Any tips for doing this right would be appreciated!

Comment: if you found a solution, it was good to answer the question yourself, but now you should mark the best answer (it can be yours) as the accepted answer by clicking the green checkmark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
X,Y = np.mgrid[-10:10,-10:10]
idx = (X**2 + Y**2 > 2)
X, Y = X[idx], Y[idx]
```

The problem is that you no longer have 2D arrays, which may be an issue for things like matplotlib.

---

Seeing your own answer, and that you basically want to replace with `0` entries not fulfilling the condition, it is probably going to be cleaner and more efficient to do:

```
idx = X**2 + Y**2 > 2
X[~idx] = 0
Y[~idx] = 0
```

Comment: This doesn't remove coordinates for which `x**2 + y**2 <= 2`, only `x**2 + y**2 < 2`

Comment: @askewchan It does now. Thanks for the bug checking!

Comment: Unfortunately, I do need 2D arrays because I am using matplotlib.  However, in trying to make your code work I figured out an alternative acceptable solution.

Comment: I like this update; it's more compact than my solution.  Do you know where I can find documentation on the `~idx` syntax?

Comment: @Bill The `~` is the `bitwise_not` operator. You could skip it by setting `idx = X**2 + Y**2 <= 2`. What is going on there is boolean array indexing, which is described [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays).

Answer (score 4):

I was able to achieve the result that I needed using `numpy.where`, by filtering each array individually, but referencing both in the `where` condition:

```
X,Y = np.mgrid[-10:10,-10:10]
X,Y = np.where(X**2 + Y**2 > 2, X, 0), np.where(X**2 + Y**2 > 2, Y, 0)
```

This results in new 2D arrays, which is what I needed for matplotlib.  Thanks to everyone who took the time to look at this question!